# Migrated to CF2018 and having problems with sessions

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I recently migrated an app from CF2010 to CF2018 and we're having problems on sessions when a user logs in.

Adding some dumps and aborts I see that the session is successfully set on a valid login, but when using cflocation or cfheader it loses the session (application.cfc reruns onSessionStart).  My application.cfc looks like:

```
this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,8,0,0);
this.sessionmanagement = true;
this.clientmanagement = false;
this.sessiontimeout = createTimeSpan(0,0,20,0);
this.scriptProtect = "all";  
this.setClientCookies = true;
this.showDebugOutput = false;
this.enablecfoutputonly = false;
```

onSessionStart is pretty simple:

```
public void function onSessionStart() {
  lock scope="session" type="exclusive" timeout="10" {
    session.started = now();
    session.loggedIn = false;
  };
  lock scope="application" type="exclusive" timeout="5" {
    application.sessions = application.sessions + 1;
  };

  writeLog(file = "g-session-log", type = "information", application = "no", text = "session started:");
};
```

I can see the log file gain an entry when the login page is processed.  In the server admin I have "Use J2EE session variables" and "Enable Session Variables" both checked.  Cookie timeout is 1440, HTTPOnly is checked and "Disable updating ColdFusion internal cookies using ColdFusion tags/functions" is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue - answering in case anyone else has this problem.  In my `onApplicationStart()` I set an http and https siteroot.  On `<cflocation>` called `application.secureSiteRoot` but because I was moving the SSL cert over for testing I had it set to http, not https.  That prevented the cookies from being set.